Acid-base balance in plants
Question: How do plants extrude excess acid/alkali, at the level of the whole organism?
I have no expertise in botany at all. I come from a medical background and sought to find a similar treatment of acid-base physiology in plants, but to no avail. The specific issue that is bothering me is this: in humans, the lungs and kidneys are the ultimate regulators of acid-base homeostasis, extruding excess acids in the form of expiration and urine, respectively. Note that this statement makes no mention of cells at all; at the level of the whole organism, an excess of acid intake over alkali intake must be balanced by a net excretion of acid. The lungs and kidneys can be understood to provide this function.
In the case of plants, however, I could not find any organism-level discussion. I get that plant cells extrude H+ via PM-ATPases, but where do all those ions go eventually, if there isn't an botanic equivalent of urine?
I managed to find the following quotes.

Abrupt pH shifts are first curbed by buffers and then reversed by membrane transport. The latter predominantly involves the apoplast or the vacuole as either final or temporary sink (...) Due to the small volume of apoplastic fluid, minor ion translocation across the plasma membrane will alter the ion concentrations and activities quickly and considerably, leading to potentially unfavourable conditions for the surrounding cells. Therefore, protons net exported into the apoplastic space will have to be taken up by neighbouring cells or must be transported elsewhere within the plant body. Where the H+-exporting cells are embedded in a tissue, not all protons exported may readily flow away but will acidify the apoplast (as demonstrated with fusicoccin)[.] (Felle HH, 2001, Plant Biol. link)


To reduce the intracellular acid load, net H+ transport out of the cell or tissue has to be the ultimate goal. Organisms may differ considerably in their ability to accomplish this. Whereas a (fresh-) water plant may find it easy to get rid of exported protons, a tissue cell within a terrestrial plant must export the protons into the
apoplast, a rather thin layer with a volume comparable to that of the cytoplasm. Since this provides a poor H+ sink, a stimulated pump will rapidly acidify the apoplast (...) This will cause either thermodynamic stalling of the pump or favour H+ re-uptake into the cell and thus generate futile H+ circling. For this reason, H+ pumping into the apoplast of terrestrial plant tissues will have to be low to limit excessive acidification. (Felle HH, 2005, Ann Bot. link)

Such passages seem to suggest that the H+ exported into the apoplast must again be moved to somewhere else, in order to maintain homeostasis. Common sense suggests that these routes must comprise guttation + root exudation, but I cannot find any sources that explicitly state this. Is my understanding correct? If so, are there any papers that I could consult regarding this issue?

I was able to find several papers discussing rhizosphere pH regulation, driven in one study in wheat by exudation of acidic compounds. Rhizosphere exudate is probably the closest thing to the urine analog you are looking for:

We propose that the secretion of multiple types of metabolites with a –COOH group is an important pH regulation strategy for alkali-stressed wheat plants.

This seems to have been shown in various experimental studies in some alkali-tolerant grasses:

To identify the physiological mechanisms involved in this plant’s resistance to alkali stress, the relative growth rates, the quantities and compositions of organic acids accumulated and secreted through the roots into the rhyzosphere, the concentrations of inorganic ions, proline and other solutes accumulating in the shoots were measured. The results show that the organic acid constituents in the shoots and roots were much the same. These were predominantly malic acid, oxalic acid, citric acid and succinic acid. The total concentration of organic acids in the shoots increased strongly with increasing alkali stress.
...
The main organic acid accumulated was not only an important organic osmotic regulator, but also an important negative charge contributor, playing important roles in ionic balance and pH adjustment.

One notable conclusion from this is that the external abiotic environment is a much more import pH stressor than internal pH homeostasis. Plants go to a lot of trouble to regulate in response to environment. Regulation of external soil pH also has the nice side effect of increasing the bioavailability of various inorganic ions like K+.
Root organic acid exudates are also a mechanism for symbiosis with beneficial microbiota. For a review discussing several of these benefits, see here.
